# Manage error log in Java

Tags: java, logging, error-handling

I have an issues with the file Error.log which is generate by Java.
It's too big (Currently >10Go) I can't open it with Notepad++/SublimeText etc.. and as it's on a dedicated computer, transfering it with Teamviewers make Teamviewer crash.

I would like to know if there is a way to configure how the error.log file is generated.
I want to have one file each days and only keep the last 7 days.
Can I configure Java to do that ? Or do I need to redirect System.err to a file ?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `Java`. I assume its a Java Application... if so: what is it's name? Where is the log file located?

Comment: Yeah sorry it's a java application called apes, it's launch with "java -jar APES.jar" and the log file is beside the jar file, if I can put log files in a folder it'll be wonderfull :D

Comment: for getting the file off the computer, try zipping it. Text files like logs are usually reduced massively (if the zip tool handles 10GB input file). Make sure to leave the original file in place in case the app is still running.

Comment: What is APES? `apes - Audio Program for Editing Sound`? Something else? Is it freely available somewhere?

Comment: No it's a software which is used for behavior experimentation on monkey (no monkey is being hurt). But there is a pat in pending so I'm not able to share anythings of the software. I just took the project and have to clean every problem that the old team left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some java libraries you can use to manage log files the most popular log4j. So if you can edit the source code, this library can help achieve what you want. Besides that there are some tools that can handle large log files and give you search functionnality, edit reports and so on.  try look for splunk, elasticsearch, kibana ..

Comment: I'll check that, I have access to the source code so I'll will add log4j, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have source code available just change log4j configuration. If not then try following
create a job which checks consistently to the log file and rename this when size exceeds some configurable value.